# Django PostgreSQL query not returning any values

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x

Django version: 1.9.3
Python version: 3
PostgreSQL version: 9.4.6

**Summary**

I am trying to get the total count of "check_date" grouped by username. Both queries seem to be good, but Django does not return any result after running it. The same works as expected in PostgreSQL.

**Details**

Database Table:

```
 id |  username   | check_date 
----+-------------+------------
  1 | john        | 2016-03-26
  2 | john        | 2016-03-26
  3 | samantha    | 2016-03-26
  4 | samantha    | 2016-03-26
  5 | samantha    | 2016-03-26
```

Django Class:

```
class UserTable(models.Model):
 username = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 check_date = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

Django query:

```
date = str(u'\''+date+'\'')
userCount = UserTable.objects.filter(check_date=date)
userCount = userCount.values('username').annotate(total = models.Count('username'))
```

*Notice that since Django removes the quotes and thus affecting the query, I had to "tweak" the date variable (even the date field is not a DateField for now) before passing it to the filter.*

Result of the Django Query ==> `print (userCount.query)`

```
SELECT "users_table"."username", COUNT("users_table"."username") AS "total" FROM "users_table" WHERE "users_table"."check_date" = '2016-03-26' GROUP BY "users_table"."username"
```

Running the query in PostgreSQL:

```
   username  | total 
-------------+-------
 john        |    2
 samantha    |    3
```

Running the query in Django:

```
[]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: afaik Django manages quoting the values on its own, so you want to use `date = str(date)` instead of `date = str(u'\''+date+'\'')`

Comment: I tried that, same problem. In theory str(item) should take care of it, but after sending the query Django removes the quotes. However that's not my problem right now since the generated query works fine in PostgreSQL. I am just not getting the results when I run the query from Django.

Comment: It's not true to say that Django removes the quotes, and also not a good idea to rely on `UserCount.query` as a full representation of the query Django sends to Postgres. It isn't, and Django doesn't remove the quotes. Try the query again, passing the original `date` object.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman. Could you please share the best way to the see final query? When I look at the final query passing the object it is: "SELECT "users_table"."username", COUNT("users_table"."username") AS "total" FROM "users_table" WHERE "users_table"."check_date" = 2016-03-26 GROUP BY "users_table"."username"", which fails in Postgre since it does not include the quotes. Based on other sources one can either use the UserCount.query option or enable logging, reason why I thought that I could rely on the first one for testing purposes.

Comment: I think there is somewhere a method/property `as_sql`, which should give you the final query